# Delete items in an array that are in another array

Tags: powershell

I'm stuck with my script. 
I need to compare two arrays, one is the result of a query, the other one of a content of a file:

```
$Array1 = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "select name from person"

$Array2 = Get-Content ".\Myfile.txt" #the file is a set of one item
every line
```

Now, in $Array2 there are items that I would like to delete from the $Array1.

How can I do this? 
Thank you for yr help!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use the [`Where-Object` cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849715.aspx) to filter `$Array1` based on what is in `$Array2`:

```
$Array1 = $Array1 |Where-Object { $Array2 -notcontains $_ }
```

That works if `Invoke-Sqlcmd` returns simple strings. If not, you could do something like:

```
$Array1 = $Array1 |Where-Object { $Array2 -notcontains $_.someProperty }
```

Comment: Keep in mind, if the array items are strings, and this filter returns a single item, you will get unexpected results iterating through the resultant array as each item will be individual characters of the string instead of a single array of one string. To fix this, cast the whole line to [Array]. Example: $filtered = [Array]($a | Where { $b -notcontains $_ })

Answer (score 3):

If performance is an issue, you can get faster results constructing an alternating regex from one of the arrays, and using it as an array operator against the other.

```
$Array1 = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query "select name from person"

$Array2 = Get-Content ".\Myfile.txt" #the file is a set of one item
every line

$regex = ‘(?i)^(‘ + (($Array2 |foreach {[regex]::escape($_)}) –join “|”) + ‘)$’

$Array1 -notmatch $regex
```

Explanation of the code to build the regex [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/02/18/speed-up-array-comparisons-in-powershell-with-a-runtime-regex/).