# Subtract a string variable from another string variable

Tags: powershell

How can I remove the items in `$b` from `$a`?

```
$a = "aa","bb","cc","dd","ee"

$b = "bb","dd"
```

Do you know a good solution?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: A foreach loop and comparing each line with if command. I think there should be an easier way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete items in an array that are in another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38243736/delete-items-in-an-array-that-are-in-another-array)

Comment: You've actually got two arrays of strings, I assume you didn't know this so couldn't find the answer using the search. I'm voting to close as a duplicate as this has been covered before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Compare-Object` command is the easiest way of doing this, although it's not very robust, if this is for use in production you may want to roll a more thought-out solution.

```
$c = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $a -DifferenceObject $b | ? SideIndicator -eq '<=' | Select -Expand InputObject
```

Another way which is quite similar but more readable in my opinion is:

```
$c = $a | ? {$_ -notin $b}
```

Another way would be using the `Group-Object` command, and selecting unique entries, but this will include ones which were in `$b` but NOT in `$a`.

```
$c = $a+$b | Group-Object | ? Count -eq 1 | Select -Expand Group
```

all of these methods will output:

```
aa
cc
ee
```