# Is there a simple way to remove items from a list in powershell?

Tags: powershell

In powershell you can use the `..` range notation to define a list of numbers. You can then add another list by using the `+=` notation.  For example, like this:

```
$s = (1..5)
$s += (6..10)
$s 
1
2
3
...
10
```

I then expected that you should be able to use `-=` to remove a list of items in a similar fashion, using something like `$s -= (6..10)`. But this resulted in the error:

`Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] does not contain a method named 'op_Subtraction'`

*Is there a simple way to also remove items in a list using some similar notation?*

References:

- [about_operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.4)
- [about_assignment_operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_assignment_operators?view=powershell-7.4)

Comment: Not removing but this functionality may be useful: `$s=$s[(0..5)]`. It sets the elements between 0-5 to the `$s` array and the (6..10) will be removed. It's like a value changing, not a removing method but can be useful as I hope. Or `For` method can be used for removing elements one by one: `For($Counter = 5; $Counter -lt 10; $Counter++) { $s[$Counter]=$Null }` removes the elements at (6..10)

Comment: PS is written using Net library.  So any Net method will work.  Try $s.RemoveAt(x) or $s.RemoveRange(index, count)

Comment: ^ With the exception on fixed arrays which is what is created when using the `+=` operator. You can filter it out if that's the case and reassign the variable with the new value, or create a mutable list from the get-go

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there is no built-in short-hand (operator) to remove items from an Array/List. A `Where` filter is probably the easiest way to achieve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38243736/delete-items-in-an-array-that-are-in-another-array)

```
$s = $s | Where-Object { (6..10) -notcontains $_ }
```

Unfortunately, operators like `op_Subtraction` can only be overloaded for custom classes/types, not for standard types like Array.

Comment: You can use the `?` shortcut, as well.  ```$s = $s | ? { $_ -notin 6..10 }```

Comment: Thank you @mklement0. The $ in front of `$(...)` was not intended (and is not needed). I stick with the `-notcontains` out of habit (since it works with other data types) but `-notin` is probably indeed best here.

Comment: Shortening the `Where` to `?` is an option, yes.

Comment: Thanks for updating; strictly speaking, given PowerShell's [operator precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operator_Precedence), you don't even need `(...)`. `-contains` and `-in` and their negated variants are functionally equivalent, only with the operands reversed, so they both work with all data types.

Comment: Many great answers here, but I choose yours because of simplicity, and with the added brief version by Mark. I learned a lot from the other answers as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Your sample data has integers in a `System.Object[]` variable, so in this case you *could* filter by value rather than by index, but the answer below assumes the more general case of filtering by index, where you want to remove the items at *index* `x..y` rather than items with *values* `x..y`...

### System.Object[]

Note that the [assignment by addition operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_assignment_operators?view=powershell-7.4#the-assignment-by-addition-operator) doesn't technically *append* any items to the original array - it returns a *new* array that contains the result of concatenating the two operands:

```
# make two references to the original array
$s1 = 1..5
$s2 = $s1
[object]::ReferenceEquals($s1, $s2)
# True

# "add" more values to the array - note this will actually create a new array instance that contains 1..10
$s1 += 6..10
[object]::ReferenceEquals($s1, $s2)
# False

# the new instance contains 1..10
$s1.Length
# 10

# but the original array still only contains values 1..5
$s2.Length
# 5
```

You can do something similar for "subtraction" using the range operator to concatenate the items *before* the indices you want to remove and the items *after* the indices you want to remove:

```
$s1 = 1..10

# "remove" items at index 5-7 (i.e. values 6-8) by concatenating items
# at 0..4 and 8..9 into another new array
$s1 = $s1[0..4] + $s1[8..9]

$s1
# 1
# 2
# 3
# 4
# 5
# 9
# 10
```

### System.ArrayList

In general though, it's more efficient to use a mutatable type like an [ArrayList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=net-8.0) if you plan to perform lots of "addition" and "subtraction" operations as creating copies of arrays during each operation can be computationally expensive (cpu and memory) if you do it repeatedly or with very large arrays.

```
# create a new arraylist containing the values 1..5
$s1 = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new(1..5)
$s1.Count
# 5

# append the additional items to the list
$s1.AddRange(6..10)
$s1.Count
# 10

# remove items at indices 5-7
$s1.RemoveRange(5, 3)
$s1
# 1
# 2
# 3
# 4
# 5
# 9
# 10
```

Note the use of `Count` rather than `Length` for an ArrayList.

### Linq

Another slightly more convoluted approach is to do the removal using the Linq [`Where<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource,Int32,Boolean>)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-8.0#system-linq-enumerable-where-1(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-func((-0-system-int32-system-boolean)))) extension method overload that passes the value *and* the index...

```
$s1 = 1..10

$s1 = [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Where(
   $s1,
   [Func[object, int, bool]] {
       param($item, $index)
       ($index -lt 5) -or ($index -gt 7)
   }
)

$s1
# 1
# 2
# 3
# 4
# 5
# 9
# 10
```

This still creates a whole new array and selects the filtered ranges into it so there's still a performance issue to be mindful of...

Comment: It's a bit funny that `RemoveRange()` works differently than `AddRange()`, but useful to know.

Answer (score 1):

To complement the existing, helpful answers with **another value-filtering alternative that returns a *new* array**:

LINQ also has an **[`::Except()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except) method**, which has the following constraints:

- It **produces the *set difference*** between two input enumerables, i.e. *duplicates are eliminated*.
- While using *strongly* typed input enumerables is typical and generally preferable for better performance, using PowerShell's `[object[]]`-typed arrays - which are therefore capable of containing a *mix* of specific types - as inputs works too.

As most LINQ methods do, `::Except()` returns a "lazy" enumerable (to be enumerated *on demand*), whose enumeration can be forced by wrapping the call in `@(...)`, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--), which also yields an `[object[]]` array as the result.

If the above constraints are acceptable, the solution below seems to perform much better than a `Where-Object`-based one.

**[PowerShell (Core)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) *v7.3+*** solution (where explicit generic method calls are supported):

```bash
# PS v7.3+
# -> @(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
$setDifference = 
  @([Linq.Enumerable]::Except[object](1..10, 6..10))
```

**In earlier versions, including in *Windows PowerShell*** you need to guide PowerShell's method overload resolution with explicit casts (curiously, casting *one* of the inputs seems to be enough; also note the need to enclose the range expression in `(...)`, because casts have [higher precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operator_Precedence) than `..`, the [range operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#range-operator-)):

```bash
# PS 7.2- and Windows PowerShell
$setDifference = 
  @([Linq.Enumerable]::Except([object[]] (1..10), 6..10))
```

Comment: I like the set *difference*, and I'm sure it will come in handy somewhere else, one day.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove individual elements by value with an arraylist:

```
[collections.arraylist]$array = 1..10
$array

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10


$array.remove

OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
void Remove(System.Object obj)
void IList.Remove(System.Object value)


6..10 | % { $array.remove($_) }
$array

1
2
3
4
5
```

Trying something with objects.  I guess you need the exact pointer or object reference to remove it.

```
[collections.arraylist]$array = echo Joe John | % { [pscustomobject]@{name=$_} }
$array

name
----
Joe
John


$a = $array[0]
$array.remove($a)
$array

name
----
John
```

Answer (score 0):

Since PowerShell allows you to use negative indexes and it also allows you to reverse the indexes order, for clarity and conciseness, I would do something like the following:

```
PS /Users/m> $s = (1..10); $s;   
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
PS /Users/m> $s = $s[-10..-6]; $s;
1
2
3
4
5
```